# Python: Modified sorting order for a list

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, comparison

I have a list:

```
['24/2', '24/3', '25/2', '6']
```

I'd like to sort it so that it would come out as

```
['6','24/2','24/3','25/2']
```

However, the `sorted()` function returns

```
['24/2', '24/3', '25/2', '6']
```

Is there a way to change this (not permanently for strings, but just in this instance)?

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't really explained what criteria you want to use to sort the list. I mean, I could guess, but for future reference it helps if you're more clear about that.

Comment: Almost any answer when searching for "python sorting" on this site would have give you the answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the middle two elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> items = ['24/2', '24/3', '25/2', '6']
>>> sorted(items, key=lambda s: [int(n) for n in s.split('/')])
['6', '24/2', '24/3', '25/2']
```